# Understanding results of PHP's mb_detect_encoding and mb_check_encoding functions

Tags: php, character-encoding, windows-1252

I'm trying to understand the logic of the two functions [`mb_detect_encoding`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) and [`mb_check_encoding`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.mb-check-encoding.php), but the documentation is poor. Starting with a very simple test string

```
$string = "\x65\x92";
```

Which is lowercase 'a' followed by a curly quote mark when using Windows-1252 encoding.

I get the following results:

```
mb_detect_encoding($string,"Windows-1252"); // false
mb_check_encoding($string,"Windows-1252"); // true
mb_detect_encoding($string,"ISO-8859-1"); // ISO-8859-1
mb_check_encoding($string,"ISO-8859-1"); // true
mb_detect_encoding($string,"UTF-8",true); // false
mb_detect_encoding($string,"UTF-8"); // UTF-8
mb_check_encoding($string,"UTF-8"); // false
```

- I don't understand why `mb_detect_encoding` gives "ISO-8859-1" for the string but not "Windows-1252", when, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252, the byte `x92` is defined in the Windows-1252 character encoding but not in ISO-8859-1.
- Secondly, I don't understand how `mb_detect_encoding` can return `false`, but `mb_check_encoding` can return `true` for the same string and same character encoding.
- Finally, I don't understand why the string can ever be detected as UTF-8, strict mode or not. The byte `x92` is a continuation byte in UTF-8, but in this string, it's following a valid character byte, not a leading byte for a sequence.

Comment: It's quite interesting to stumble across this question. I'm the author of the new implementation of these functions in PHP 8.0/8.1. I think you will find they behave more consistently now. If you still have any questions, ask me any time.

Comment: This is really helpful since I've been running into a weird issue with this too. Given this: 
mb_detect_encoding("m2", "ASCII,JIS,UTF-8,UTF-16,UTF-32,EUC-JP,SJIS,ISO-8859-1")
it returns UTF-18, while anything else I've tested ("m1", "m3", "ma") all return ASCII. I think I'll be trying mb_check_encoding instead

Answer (score 2):

Your examples do a good job of showing why `mb_detect_encoding` should be used sparingly, as it is not intuitive and sometimes logically wrong. If it must be used, **always** pass in `strict = true` as the third parameter (so non-UTF8 strings don't get reported as UTF-8.

It's a bit more reliable to run `mb_check_encoding` over an array of desired encodings, in order of likelihood/priority. For example:

```
$encodings = [
    'UTF-8',
    'Windows-1252',
    'SJIS',
    'ISO-8859-1',
];

$encoding = 'UTF-8';
$string = 'foo';
foreach ($encodings as $encoding) {
    if (mb_check_encoding($string, $encoding)) {
        // We'll assume encoding is $encoding since it's valid
        break;
    }
}
```

The ordering depends on your priorities though.